# Equivalent of <() for sh?

Tags: node.js, shell, sh, zsh

I have a script that runs in my zsh.

```
cat foo.txt <(node bar.js) > out.txt
```

This little script is configured in a node.js module which uses `/bin/sh` for execution. The problem is that sh fails at the `<`

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The goal is to concatenate contents of foo.txt and the output of an executed script into a single out.txt

Can I somehow achieve the same thing using sh?

Comment: FYI, `<()` isn't just a zsh thing -- it's available in Korn shell back to the ksh88 release, and bash for quite some time as well.

Comment: Fortunately, the specific use case you have here is one that doesn't use the feature for anything too tricky. More interesting use cases would be harder to replace, but for this trivial one, you have some fine answers already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect as the original script by grouping commands within `{...}` like this:

```
{ cat foo.txt; node bar.js; } > out.txt
```

Using `<(...)` just so that you can `cat` it is awkward and inefficient. Using grouping like this is better and more portable, so I think it's an improvement over the original script.

Comment: I ended up accepting this because it could support as many file/output fragments as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-` stdin-marker when running `cat`, and redirect the output of your `node` command to `cat` using plain piping:

```
node bar.js | cat foo.txt - > out.txt
```

This is pretty standard.  It should work in any shell.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally equivalent to process substitution is the use of a named pipe (and depending on what the underlying system supports, is how `bash` implements process substitution).

```
# Create a named pipe - it's like a file, but of limited size
# A process that writes to it will block until another process reads some
# data and frees up some space for more output
mkfifo node_js_output

# Run node in the background, redirecting its output to the pipe
node bar.js > node_js_output

# Concatenate foo.txt and the output from node to out.txt
cat foo.txt node_js_output > out.txt

# When node bar.js completes, it will exit. Once cat has finished
# reading everything written to node_js_output, it will exit as well,
# leaving behind the "empty" node_js_output. You can delete it now
rm node_js_output
```